# implement conditions relative table django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two Models

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,related_name='child')
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    type = models.BooleanField()
```

I have implement this logic on serializer.py

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Login
        fields = ('id', 'parent', 'child_name','type')


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Catcher
        fields = ('id','name', 'child')
```

I hit a query on Parent and get all the data from child table but i want implement condition on child table to get type = 1 only

```
a = Parent.objects.get(pk = 1)
serializer = ParentSerializer(a, many=True)
```

it return me this json

```
{
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Rijo",
    "child": [
        {
          "id": 98,
          "name": "Child 1",
          "type" : 1
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "Child 2",
          "type" : 0
        }

    ]
}
```

But i want only type 1 child, how can i implement condition on child query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Implement method or property in parent model:

   ```
   class Parent(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

       def first_type_children(self):
           return self.child.filter(type=1)
   ```
2. Use it as `source` in serializer field:

   ```
   class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       child = ChildSerializer(source='first_type_children', many=True, read_only=True)
   ```

Comment: Please, elaborate. What exactly is not working? Is output the same as before?

Comment: Exception raised in callable attribute "first_type_children"; original exception was: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'child'

Comment: Please help me sort out this

Comment: self.child.filter It is table name or object?

Comment: Try to execute: `a = Parent.objects.get(pk = 1)` and than `a.child.all()`.

Comment: This means that the models in the code and the models in your answer are different. Please, check line `parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,related_name='child')` in `Child` model. Are you sure that it has the attribute `related_name`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139479/discussion-between-zymud-and-jaskaran-singh-rajal).

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Method:**

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = serializers.SerializerMethodField('first_type_children')

    def first_type_children(self,obj):
        child_objects = Child.objects.filter(type=1,parent=obj)
        # child_objects = self.child_set.filter(type=1) 
        serializers = ChildSerializer(child_objects,many=True)
        return serializers.data
```

otherwise, you can define:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   child = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_child(self,obj):
        child_objects = self.child_set.filter(type=1) 
        serializers = ChildSerializer(child_objects,many=True)
        return serializers.data
```

however I would recommend to use @zymud methods by making this a property in your model. As it will reduce your code.

*eg: If you're using the QuerySet / filter in multiple places, you could use a getter function on your model, and then even drop the 'source' kwarg for the Serializer / Field.*

1. models.py

   ```
   class Parent(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

       def first_type_children(self):
           return self.child.filter(type=1)
   ```
2. in your serializer

   ```
   class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       first_type_children = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
   ```

Hopefully this help someone!